# Getting a substring between two tags C/C++

Tags: c++

Hello I am creating a parser of sorts in C/C++ it is rather simple i just want to be able to get a string from to tags `"(" and ")"` using C/C++ i know that the logic is like find first tag and increment a number every single char that is found until the next tag is found. But i suck a logic so if someone could at least give me a function that could help.

Edit:I see that C/C++ string functions are nothing alike so just C++ will do.

Comment: pick a language. The C answer and the C++ answer will not be anything alike.

Comment: You won't get far in a programming career if you suck at algorithm design. You should either get better at it (by, e.g., tackling the above problem yourself and coming back to SO when stuck, and presenting whatever code you managed to write yourself) or consider another career.

Answer (score 0):

You seem unsure of the differences between string handling in C and in C++. Your description seems to imply wanting to do it in a C-style way.

```
void GetTag(const char *str, char *buffer)
{
    buffer[0] = '\0';
    char *y = &buffer[0];

    const char *x = &str[0];
    bool copy = false;

    while (x != NULL)
    {
        if (*x == '(')
            copy = true;
        else if (*x == ')' && copy)
        {
            *y = '\0';
            break;
        }
        else if (copy)
        { 
            *y = *x;
            y++;
        }
        ++x;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, the C++ way is to use the std::string which is safer because it's not fiddling with pointers, and arguably easier to read and understand.

```
std::string GetTag(const std::string &str)
{
    std::string::size_type start = str.find('(');
    if (start != str.npos)
    {
        std::string::size_type end = str.find(')', start + 1);
        if (end != str.npos)
        {
            ++start;
            std::string::size_type count = end - start;
            return str.substr(start, count);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Well, at least you didn't return a dangling pointer, but returning a pointer to a `static` buffer is hardly a recommended method.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks, I had tried to keep the C example simple and comparable with the C++ example as far as inputs and outputs. But I agree and I've changed it to take an input parameter.